# Deploying sfdx-converted metadatas to an org with a filtered package.xml

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

In a DevOps chain, I have a SFDX project.

I want to **deploy only parts of this SFDX Project** to an org, using a **custom package.xml**

My actions are :

- **sfdx force:source:convert -d tmp/deployDemoQuali/**
- **replace tmp/deployDemoQuali/package.xml by my own custom package.xml**
- **sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d tmp/deployDemoQuali/ -w 60 -u DemoQuali**

Problem is that even with filtered package.xml, fdx force:mdapi:deploy seems to take the full content of tmp/deployDemoQuali/

How can I **filter content** of tmp/deployDemoQuali/ to **keep only the items listed in my custom package.xm**l ?

Thanks ! :)

Comment: Isn't this a defect of sfdx force:mdapi:deploy?

There's a major inconsistency with the --zipfile option.  sfdx expects the zipfile and package file to match 1:1.  This causes a problem if I only want to deploy a single class from my project and not the entire contents of package.xml.

This is not how ant migration is implemented.  With the migration tool I can create a zipfile containing only a single class and the /entire/ package.xml and only the class deploys.  sfdx force:mdapi:deploy complains for every missing item from the package.

Is this the same problem you're experiencing?

Comment: it's exactly that: if the folder or zipfile doesn't contain exactly the content described in package.xml file, you have an error. Use of sfdx-essentials plugin will make this problem disappear :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So ... I finally created a **sfdx plugin** allowing to do that

https://github.com/nvuillam/sfdx_metadatas_filtering

- Install it

  **sfdx plugins:install sfdx_metadatas_filtering**
- Use it

  **sfdx metadatafilter:execute -i mdapi_output_dir -p myPackage.xml -o md_api_filtered_output_dir**

Full example

```
sfdx force:source:convert -d tmp/deployDemoQuali/
sfdx metadatafilter:execute -i tmp/deployDemoQuali/ -p myPackage.xml -o tmp/deployDemoQualiFiltered/
sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d tmp/deployDemoQualiFiltered/ -w 60 -u DemoQuali
```

Warnings:

- all cases are not taken in account yet, please read carefully the README and contribute if you are in a hurry :)
- Windows users: [sfdx plugin generator](https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-plugin-generate) is bugged on windows (hardcode call of linux rm instruction) , so you may use [Git Bash](https://gitforwindows.org/) to run this code ( at least while it installs the plugin dependencies )

---

### **EDIT 26/06/2018**

It seems that several plugins are necessary to survive in this cruel world, so I joined all the ones I needed to create (including metadata filtering) into [**https://github.com/nvuillam/sfdx-essentials**](https://github.com/nvuillam/sfdx-essentials)

This is the only maintained plugin , please use it :)

---

Comment: I made my first working deployment using v 0.7.2 of the plugin, it's ready to use :)

Answer (score 0):

The approach I have taken is to use [Ant's very flexible file matching](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) to filter the set of components into a separate folder and then run the `sfdx force:source:convert` on that folder:

```
<target name="convert">
    <copy todir="./mdapi-source/staged">
        <fileset dir="./sfdx-source/int/test"/>
        <fileset dir="./sfdx-source/int/main"/>
        <fileset dir="./sfdx-source/wiz/test">
           <exclude name="**/aura/**"/>
           <exclude name="**/staticresources/**"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="./sfdx-source/wiz/main"/>
    </copy>
    <exec dir="." executable="sfdx" osfamily="unix" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="force:source:convert"/>
        <arg value="--rootdir" />
        <arg value="./mdapi-source/staged" />
        <arg value="--outputdir" />
        <arg value="./mdapi-source/cvux" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

leaving `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy` to figure out its own package.xml.

If you prefer some other scripting language, you can accomplish the same thing in that.

Comment: my custom package.xml contains exactly what I want to deploy ... with your solution, I can't use it and I must write an ant copy task to manually filter all its content ? :/ this seems long ... i'm more looking for a "ready to use" solution :/

Comment: @NicolasVuillamy I don't think compatibility with package.xml is a priority in the newer sfdx tools. If there isn't one already - someone else may know of one - then you could write your own as [sfdx is open for extension](http://www.wadewegner.com/2017/03/creating-a-plugin-for-the-sf-cli/) and share with the wider community.

Comment: yipee, I have to work for Salesforce for free to solve a lack in their functions :) Meanwhile ... as I don't have the time, I'll probably deploy in a scratch, then make a mdapi:retrieve with my package.xml, then use it for demployment .... Ugly, but it should work

Comment: @NicolasVuillamy Keep checking back here though: someone may know a direct answer to the question. (I mentioned being able to add to the tooling because closed tooling is even worse where you have to bodge something on the side.)

Comment: Started to do a plugin .... no time to wait for SFDC, but i'm still angry ;) Thanks for the tip about the plugin generator :) https://github.com/nvuillam/sfdx_metadatas_filtering , prototype works for some of the first metadatas, will complete it tomorrow

Comment: @NicolasVuillamy Yeah it has taken me years to lower my expectations enough to not get frustrated. Suggest when you are done you answer your own question with the link to your solution.